# Deleting an entry with JSON in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have a dynamically generated table that also have this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-task" 
value="{{$contact->id}}">delete</button>
```

At the end of the code I have this:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
```

The button triggers this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.delete-task').click(function(){
    var contact_id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: adressbook_edit + '/' + contact_id,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#contact" + contact_id).remove();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
}
```

Which is supposed to lead to my routes like this:

```
Route::delete('/adressbook_edit/{$contact_id?}',function($contact_id){
    $contact = addressbook::destroy($contact_id);
    return Response::json($contact);
});
```

I am expecting to delete the entry in the database, however I get a 404 error. The direction is apparently correct. Here is the error I get:

> DELETE http://myip/adressbook_edit/2 404 (Not Found) send @ app.js:26
>   ajax @ app.js:25 (anonymous) @ adressbook.js:79 dispatch @ app.js:25
>   g.handle @ app.js:25 adressbook.js:87
>
> Error: Object {readyState: 4,
>   getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function,
>   setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

Adressbook.js is where the aforementioned ajax function is called.

Comment: Is that correct `delete('/adressbook_edit/{$contact_id?}'`? I think `$` and `?` are not needed. Try with `delete('/adressbook_edit/{contact_id}'`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos tried with no difference

Comment: In addition to What @AntonisTsimourtos suggested Your url attribute in the ajax request need to be something like: `url: 'adressbook_edit/' + contact_id` or `url: '{{ url("adressbook_edit") }}' + '/' + contact_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your ajax url to this:

```
 url: '/adressbook_edit/' + contact_id
```

And also change your route to this:

```
Route::delete('/adressbook_edit/{contact_id}',function($contact_id){
    $contact = addressbook::destroy($contact_id);
    return Response::json($contact);
});
```